# Force only one session by user in domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

It's possible to force the users in a Windows domain to only have one active log in in the same time? How to do it?

Comment: By session, do you mean only log in from one machine at a time?

Comment: @squillman, yes, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Avoiding shared accounts on an Active Directory environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/82276/avoiding-shared-accounts-on-an-active-directory-environment)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jliendos link

3rd party userlock software that works with windows 2008

http://www.isdecisions.com/en/software/userlock

More info on limitlogin

http://davidhazar.blogspot.com/2010/09/microsoft-limit-login-and-login-scripts.html